# Android Empty gaps between words TextView

Tags: android

I'm building a view. For some reason it looks very different between the XML Layout Editor and the view on the device.

On Editor:
[image: On Editor]

On Device:
[image: On Device]

The Device is an S8, both on the editor and the physical device.
On the device you can notice a big space that obviously fits for the word, yet the TextView decided to leave it empty for some reason.

This is the XML for the whole view, "messageText" is the TextView in question.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingStart="16dp"
android:paddingTop="6dp"
android:paddingEnd="16dp"
android:paddingBottom="6dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageUser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
    android:textColor="#ffff"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Amy" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:textColor="#33FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/messageUser"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/messageUser"
    tools:text="Today at 4:15 PM" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/messageText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
    android:textColor="#B3FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/messageUser"
    tools:text="You have to get a new version to get changes, silly girl!" />
```

What's wrong? Why is the TextView leaving extra spaces? Why is the text on the device wider than the one in the editor? 
I've been developing android for a long time now, and this isn't in any way explainable for me.

**Edit 1**

Background on text:
[image: Background on textview]

Now I'm not even sure how Android TextView works.
Why did the text alignment changed when the text became longer? It's the same text, just a few extras.

Comment: both the devices might be of different resolutions and dpis.

Comment: @KaranMer it's the same DPI, both are on 1080x2220

Comment: I honestly wouldn't rely on the visual editor for accuracy.

Comment: @ZUNJAE still, that doesn't explain the empty space.

Comment: by any chance are you testing on android 8.0 and above?

Comment: @KaranMer my device is 8.0

Comment: then it might be autosizing textview text. see this, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to debug if it's really the issue with TextView padding itself. Just set the background color of TextView of id `messageText` to be sure that it has extra spacing at the end.

Comment: I did, the textview goes all the way

Comment: @AhmadSattout In the screenshot, I see the text `(edited)`. Where does it come from?

Comment: It's just an indication of the message being edited, but I'm not sure why that made the text go full

Comment: @AhmadSattout I was just wondering if it's another TextView with text `(edited)` since it has different color. Are you setting any html text to the text view?

Comment: @AhmadSattout Are you using any 3rd party library? I see your XML doesn't seem using standard SDK. `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` this is not the standard constraint layout. I'm using `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout`

Comment: not html, spans. And I'm guessing you haven't been keeping up with Android libraries, Android Support have changed to AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is still not answered, but the problem is probably the font or typeface used in my app.

Comment: Please do check if any `TextView` has set the attribute `android:letterSpacing` either on the layout XMLs or either in the `res/values/styles.xml` or even in the set `AppTheme`